# Python Tkinter - Issue with snake body following snake head

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to make snake game only using tkinter.  I am currently stuck on the "generating snake body" functionality of the game,
the main issue is that the "snake body" is not following the "snake head". I can't seem to pin point why this is occurring, the logic seems as though it should work, each "snake" object gets updated to the last "snake" objects position at each iteration.

Would appreciate any help or advice with the code, thanks.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint as rand


def move_snake_up():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 0, -5)


def move_snake_down():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 0, 5)


def move_snake_left():
    canvas.move(snake_head, -5, 0)


def move_snake_right():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 5, 0)


def snake_up(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "up"


def snake_down(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "down"


def snake_left(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "left"


def snake_right(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "right"


def increase_snake_size():
    global snake
    snake_tail_position = canvas.coords(snake[len(snake) - 1])
    if snake_direction == "up":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0], snake_tail_position[3], snake_tail_position[0] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[3] + 20, fill="white"))
    if snake_direction == "down":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0], snake_tail_position[1] - 20, snake_tail_position[0] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[1], fill="white"))
    if snake_direction == "left":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[2], snake_tail_position[1], snake_tail_position[2] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[1] + 20, fill="white"))
    if snake_direction == "right":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0] - 20, snake_tail_position[1], snake_tail_position[0],
                                    snake_tail_position[1] + 20, fill="white"))


def food_collision():
    pass


def main_game():
    global snake_size
    global positions
    global snake

    if snake_direction == "up":
        move_snake_up()
    if snake_direction == "down":
        move_snake_down()
    if snake_direction == "right":
        move_snake_right()
    if snake_direction == "left":
        move_snake_left()

    if snake_size < 5:
        increase_snake_size()
        snake_size += 1

    for i in range(len(snake)):
        positions.append(canvas.coords(snake[i]))

    for i in range(len(snake) - 1):
        canvas.coords(snake[i + 1], positions[i][0], positions[i][1], positions[i][2], positions[i][3])

    canvas.after(10, main_game)


window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=1280, height=720, bg="black")
canvas.pack()
snake_size = 1
snake = []
positions = []
snake_direction = "right"
snake_head = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 20, 120, 40, fill="white")
snake.append(snake_head)
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Right>", snake_right)
canvas.bind("<Left>", snake_left)
canvas.bind("<Up>", snake_up)
canvas.bind("<Down>", snake_down)

main_game()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in the position drawing part. Instead of this

```
for i in range(len(snake) - 1):
    canvas.coords(snake[i + 1], positions[i][0], positions[i][1], positions[i][2], positions[i][3])
```

Change to

```
for i in range(len(positions) - 1):
    canvas.coords(snake[i + 1], positions[i][0], positions[i][1], positions[i][2], positions[i][3])
```

That creates:

[image: snake]

Then the drawing order should be changed,  its drawing the snake body on top of its head now.  Because the rectangle size is 20, I changed the step size to 20.

I removed a loop to speed up the game cycle, changed some `if` to `elif`. But still it gets slow after a while. The for loop slows down the drawing

```
# draw past positions of snake
for i in range(1,len(positions)):
    canvas.create_rectangle(positions[i][0], positions[i][1], positions[i][0]+20, positions[i][1]+20, fill="white")
```

Because you don't clear the screen, you can just draw the last positions which speeds up the game.

```
    # speed fix
    if len(positions) >= 2:
        lastpos = len(positions) -1
        canvas.create_rectangle(positions[lastpos][0], positions[lastpos][1], 
                                positions[lastpos][0]+20, positions[lastpos][1]+20, fill="white")
```

I'm not sure if tkinter has any type of hardware acceleration, but this trick speeds it up. Back in the day I used OpenGL. You could use [PyGame](https://pythonspot.com/snake-with-pygame/) to speed up the drawing/game process.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint as rand

def move_snake_up():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 0, -20)


def move_snake_down():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 0, 20)


def move_snake_left():
    canvas.move(snake_head, -20, 0)


def move_snake_right():
    canvas.move(snake_head, 20, 0)


def snake_up(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "up"


def snake_down(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "down"


def snake_left(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "left"


def snake_right(event):
    global snake_direction
    snake_direction = "right"


def increase_snake_size():
    global snake
    snake_tail_position = canvas.coords(snake[len(snake) - 1])
    if snake_direction == "up":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0], snake_tail_position[3], snake_tail_position[0] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[3] + 20, fill="white"))
    elif snake_direction == "down":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0], snake_tail_position[1] - 20, snake_tail_position[0] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[1], fill="white"))
    elif snake_direction == "left":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[2], snake_tail_position[1], snake_tail_position[2] + 20,
                                    snake_tail_position[1] + 20, fill="white"))
    elif snake_direction == "right":
        snake.append(
            canvas.create_rectangle(snake_tail_position[0] - 20, snake_tail_position[1], snake_tail_position[0],
                                    snake_tail_position[1] + 20, fill="white"))


def food_collision():
    pass


def main_game():
    global snake_size
    global snake_head
    global positions
    global snake
    global index

    # draw past positions of snake
    #for i in range(1,len(positions)):
    #    canvas.create_rectangle(positions[i][0], positions[i][1], positions[i][0]+20, positions[i][1]+20, fill="white")

    # speed fix
    if len(positions) >= 2:
        lastpos = len(positions) -1
        canvas.create_rectangle(positions[lastpos][0], positions[lastpos][1], 
                                positions[lastpos][0]+20, positions[lastpos][1]+20, fill="white")


    # game logic
    if snake_direction == "up":
        move_snake_up()
    elif snake_direction == "down":
        move_snake_down()
    elif snake_direction == "right":
        move_snake_right()
    elif snake_direction == "left":
        move_snake_left()

    positions.append(canvas.coords(snake_head))

    canvas.after(10, main_game)

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=1280, height=720, bg="black")
canvas.pack()
snake_size = 1
snake = []
positions = []
index = 0
snake_direction = "right"
snake_head = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 20, 120, 40, fill="white")
snake.append(snake_head)
canvas.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Right>", snake_right)
canvas.bind("<Left>", snake_left)
canvas.bind("<Up>", snake_up)
canvas.bind("<Down>", snake_down)

main_game()
window.mainloop()
```

If you don't want to see the rectangles, add an outline color to the rectangle argument.

[image: snake tkinter]

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the help and advice.

Comment: I am little confused on the first change you recommended, the code seems identical to me?

Comment: the first only goes to length of snake, which isn't equal to the length of the previous positions